# Msql Explain Query not the same Test vs local

Tags: mysql, explain

I just dump the DB from test machine to local machine and run my query below:

```
SELECT advert_id,A.category_id,A.subcategory_id,subcategory,model_id,model,make,price,price2,gst,cndtn,currency,photo_id, SUM(S.visits) AS visits
FROM adverts A
LEFT JOIN subcategories SC ON A.subcategory_id = SC.subcategory_id
LEFT JOIN photos P ON P.sale_id = A.advert_id AND P.thumb=1 AND P.sale_type_id=1
LEFT JOIN  ( 
SELECT
entity_id , visits
FROM
sitestats_ga 
WHERE 
entity_type_id=1 AND (date <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y%m%d") && date >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY), "%Y%m%d"))

) S ON A.advert_id = S.entity_id
WHERE '2015-12-02 06:44:55' >= A.datetime_added AND '2015-12-02 06:44:55' < A.datetime_removed AND A.sold_currency = '' AND (A.subcategory_id = '500' OR A.category_id = '100')
GROUP BY A.advert_id
ORDER BY visits DESC, A.datetime_added DESC
LIMIT 0,12
```

Unfortunately the result duration is different between TEST and LOCAL, to verify this I tried using `EXPLAIN` in mysql and they were different also.

**Explain result on TEST**
[image]

**Explain result on LOCAL**
[image]

Just take note that I had a fresh dump of database to my local , which means they have the same indexes and I already verified it after seeing the EXPLAIN results.

Got lucky today and run the query on PROD and the result is the same as my LOCAL, I am expecting that TEST should be the same on PROD but I think there's a discrepancy on DB , so now I want to fix the TEST environment.

How can I dig more on this issue? What do I have to do more?

Comment: The `possible_keys` are the same on both screenshots - the only thing that's different are the actually chosen `keys`. MySQL automatically picks the best keys depending on the amount of rows you've got and the current cardinalities of your data table. As shown in both screenshots, the table contents are completely different (1.1k rows vs 122k rows)

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister but they have the same indexes setting..

Comment: Yes but the actual row count of the table is also taken into account during query optimization

Comment: @NickBailey what do you mean? They have the same row count 5M+ .. I'm really confused

Comment: Is the mysql version the same? OS? Hardware? is my.cnf the same? have you optimized the table in test and local?

Comment: @BK435 they have different version.. Localhost has  5.6.17  while Test is 5.5.46 for mysql

Comment: That would be my best guess as to why you see such a diff...The query optimizer in version 5.6 is way different than in 5.5...we had alot of issues in our applications when we switched over...queries that ran fine in 5.5 seemed to bomb out in 5.6..you may want to consider using a different index in 5.6 local version...

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister "As shown in both screenshots, the table contents are completely different (1.1k rows vs 122k rows)": that was a wild conclusion...

Comment: Just checked our developer station wiki. yep the materials is mysql 5.6, so our TEST machine is outdated.. Thanks! I will try upgrading our TEST machine and see what will happen.

Comment: Glad I could help...

Answer (score 1):

What happened there is very possible because sometimes Mysql index are not exactly equal in different environment even you have the same amount of data. It is all because how you manipulate the data. For example when you delete data the index number may not refresh again for all the data, so you may still have some index pointing to the empty data. However, when you do explain , this empty index still being scanned.

You can do a test create a fresh index on one column and start insert and delete data. then re-create the same index name it different, sometimes you will see the different index number.